# Different response from UIWebView in iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am trying to load a protected docx file in `UIWebView`.

In iPad `webViewDidFinishLoad` gets fired with OfficeImport error. But in iPhone neither `webViewDidFinishLoad` nor `didFailLoadWithError` gets fired. In both cases `webViewDidStartLoad` gets fired.

Does anyone know why this dual behaviour from `UIWebView`?

Thank You.

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator or the actual device?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes this is happening on the actual Device.

Comment: Share some code with delegate methods.

Comment: Is it the same iOS version on both devices?